# applying regression on bag of words

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, regression

I have a text document and did clean the text. Now I have a list of words that I want to apply regression on, but I don't know how to do it. Can anyone please help?
And can I use other Machine learning algorithms on the list of words??

Answer (score 0):

Please provide details on what kind of prediction are you doing?

In general case(using scikit-learn):

Step-1 : Use Snowball Stemmer to stem words

Step-2 : Using this parsed Data create features and labels training and test sets.

Step-3 : Convert text vectorization to lists of numbers using tfidfvectorizer

Step-4 : As it will be a huge set of features, we need to select top 10 (or     whatever you want) Percentile using selectpercentile to remove less weighted features.

Now you can use your feature set for whatever purpose you want!

Hope this helps :)

PS: You will need to do some research on nltk and vectorizer for appropriate parameters and tuning